# Пост на стене вконтакте

Tags: php, авторизация, вконтакте

Доброго всем времени суток. Вот не поперло у меня с контактом вообще 8-(

```
Входные данные:
-старый добрый 'vk.com'
-логин
-пароль
-страница ( типа vk.com/id100000000 )
-группа ( типа vk.com/kakayatogruppa, т.е. это не страница пользователя )
```

Собственно вопрос прост: есть простая страница на хостинге, в которой есть входные переменные. Охота при загрузке страницы в фоновом режиме авторизоваться, и сделать 'пост'

```
$login = '';//логин
$passw = '';//пароль
$adres = 'vk.com/kakayatogruppa';//адрес страницы, на которую нужно прыгнуть

$text = 'Это моя первая запись';
$image = 'адрес до картинки';
```

Да, сразу гугл в помощь.. и с документацией API вконтакте немного не разобрался. Может кто подсказать, как можно с простой страницы на хостинге просто авторизоваться в фоновом режиме и сделать пост?

Никаких извратов с приложениями на андройде/ай_ос. Просто при включении определенной страницы - определенный пост на определенной стене.

Comment: посмотри атрибут action у форм вк и post'ом ( $.post() ) отправь нужные тебе данные

Comment: ммм.. даже в API такого не нашел (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу авторизации, я думаю Вы найдете. А вот с постингом у меня были в свое время проблемы. Решение есть [по этой ссылке](http://pyha.ru/forum/topic/7739.0). Если все сделаете по инструкции, то будет работать. Возникнут вопросы-обращайтесь, с удовольствием отвечу.

Comment: Начну смотреть, надеюсь разберусь.

Answer (score 1):

Вы даже не пытались найти :)
[habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/125155/) почитайте комментарии, там есть уточнения.
Ну и ссылка на нужный вам раздел документации. 
[api.vk](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.post)

Comment: @Ravel, а можете привести пример полного кода? В api и на хабре был! Там полного примера вообще нет. Авторизацию я еще могу переварить, а вот пост на стену - честно, что то космическое.

И обязательно создавать приложение для простого поста на стену? хоть бы кто подсказал

Comment: А вы статью вообще читали? Там есть пример кода, и да приложение регистрировать обязательно (Из статьи : "Для того чтобы получить доступ к API контакта из php-скрипта, нужно начать с клика по кнопке “Подключить сайт” на странице для разработчиков."). В статье как раз рассказывается и даже показывается как это делается. Так же обратите внимание на комментарии.

Comment: @Ravel, многое теперь понятно, что нужно все же через приложение. Что есть беда и печаль.

Comment: @mixalef А чем вас не устраивает приложение? Группа в которую вы собираетесь отправлять сообщения не ваша? Вам дали 2 почти готовых варианта, если не один из них не устраивает, вы можете обратится на биржу фрилансеров.

Answer (score 0):

вообще думал будет, что то:

```
function супер_мега_функция(){
    ....
}
супер_мега_функция($login, $pass, $key_api, $wall, $text, $url_image);
```

Мне чертовски жаль, что готового решения нет ни в инете, ни на хэшкоде

Comment: Проблема в защите ВК. Приходится немного его обманывать, представляясь Stand alone приложением.

Comment: Дык, это понятно, что какой то уровень защиты там должен быть. Но чер возьми согласитесь, что есть входные данные, а все остальное делается одним способом, т.е. можно из этого сделать функцию.

Ну черт с ним с харбром, пусть нет на форумах. Но здесь на хэшкоде думал есть. Носом ткнут в что то подобное.

Не уже ли я не прав?